# simple data application ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am creating data application with the following code - however 
i am getting "Customer ID was not returned. Account could not be created." constantly. Do you know why the app is not creating ID automatically?

```
namespace SmallDataApplication27._08
{
    public partial class NewCustomer : Form
    {
        //NC-2 Storage for IDENTITY values returned from database.
        private int parsedCustomerID;
        private int orderID;

        //NC-3 Specify a connection string.
        string connstr = SmallDataApplication27._08.Utility.GetConnectionString();

        public NewCustomer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //NC-4 Create account.
        private void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //NC-5 Set up and run stored procedure only if Customer Name is present.
            if (isCustomerName())
            {

                //NC-6 Create the connection.
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);

                //NC-7 Create a SqlCommand, and identify it as a stored procedure.
                SqlCommand cmdNewCustomer = new SqlCommand("Sales.uspNewCustomer", conn);
                cmdNewCustomer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //NC-8 Add input parameter from the stored procedure and specify what to use as its value.
                cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40));
                cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@CustomerName"].Value = txtCustomerName.Text;

                //NC-9 Add output parameter.
                cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                //NC-10 try-catch-finally
                try
                {
                    //NC-11 Open the connection.
                    conn.Open();

                    //NC-12 Run the stored procedure.
                    cmdNewCustomer.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //NC-13 Customer ID is an IDENTITY value from the database. 
                    this.parsedCustomerID = (int)cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value;
                    this.txtCustomerID.Text = Convert.ToString(parsedCustomerID);

                }
                catch
                {
                    //NC-14 A simple catch.

                    MessageBox.Show("Customer ID was not returned. Account could not be created.");
```

utility file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;


namespace SmallDataApplication27._08
{
    internal class Utility
    {
        internal static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            //Util-2 Assume failure.
            string returnValue = null;

            //Util-3 Look for the name in the connectionStrings section.
            ConnectionStringSettings settings =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SmallDataApp.Properties.Settings.connString"];

            //If found, return the connection string.
            if (settings != null)
                returnValue = settings.ConnectionString;

            return returnValue;
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: Ah, what a useless exception catch!. Write _catch(Exception ex)_ then show _ex,Message_ where you can see the reason of your failure

Comment: Hi Steve, thx any chance you can re-write this code? it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I didn't say that this solves your problem. I say: change the catch code catching the exception info in an exception variable (_catch(Exception ex)_) then you can see the message received with _MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)_ instead of a fixed text that tell us nothing about the real problem encountered. Now if you are so kindly to tell us the real error message then someone could help you to debug the problem

Comment: (catch(Exception ex)) message: CONNECTION STRING PROPERTY HAS NOT BEEN INITIALIZED.

Comment: This means that you have no value for the variable _connstr_ and thus the code in GetConnectionString fails for some reason. Perhaps you should check the exact spelling of "SmallDataApp.Properties.Settings.connString" and if you can use a debugger place a breakpoint in that code to see what happens there